# How to pass in an image when opening an app's scheme URL?

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code, url-scheme, wechat

WeChat is a popular iOS App, I've launched its QR code scanning page like this:

```
if let url = NSURL(string:"weixin://scanqrcode")?.absoluteURL {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```

However I need to pass in the QR image to WeChat's QR scanner as well, how do I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of parameters does WeChat accept by the scheme URL?

Comment: @YunCHEN the scheme URL doesn't seem to have parameter. Could you help give me one upvote? I think someone accidentally down voted it. thanks!

Comment: So I think it's meaningless to passing the image if the WeChat is not cracked.